# How to read the XML response element in robot framework?

Tags: xml, robotframework, parsexml

I have run SOAP API request and get the response as below using robot framework.

```
(reply){
   return = "PGP-98-Sq0awmdslfjsdssdlsifTvZUORTLe1fgVeUwaolR14QS"
}
```

I would like to retrieve the value PGP-98-Sq0awmdslfjsdssdlsifTvZUORTLe1fgVeUwaolR14QS from the response XML. I have tried to get the value using the command

```robot
${token}=    Set Variable    ${API_response_Data.return}
```

But it throws an error

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 1)
```

The actual response from the SOAP UI tools looks like below (This is just for reference).

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="something" xmlns:xsd="something">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:response xmlns:ns1="http://something.com">
         <return>PGP-98-Sq0awmdslfjsdssdlsifTvZUORTLe1fgVeUwaolR14QS</return>
      </ns1:response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have used Parse XML keyword and I get the below error.
[image]

and when I use

```
 ${Token}=    Get Element    ${API_response_Data}    .//*return
    Log    ${Token.text}
```

I get the below error.
[image]

Please let me know how to extract the value from the return tag?

Comment: Are you using an already available Robot Framework library for sending and receiving SOAP messages like SudsLibrary?

Comment: Yes, I use SudsLibrary @A.Kootstra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SudsLibrary depends on the Suds module. Sadly this module is no longer maintained and as time passes the limitations of this module are becoming clearer.

In your case the object that is returned is difficult to use. This is why I preferred to have the XML response returned and process it myself using the standard XML library.

Before sending the request you can use the [Set Return XML](http://ombre42.github.io/robotframework-sudslibrary/doc/SudsLibrary.html#Set%20Return%20Xml) keyword to enable this. Then follow the example in the XML library for keyword [Parse XML](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Parse%20Xml) to obtain the actual value

Comment: it worked for me. Thanks for the help. I am able to get the token now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use robot framework's [XML library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html) to parse the response XML and then get the text of the specific element. For example:

```robot
Demo
    ${root}=    Parse XML   soap_res.xml
    ${return}=  Get Element     ${root}     .//*return
    Log     ${return.text}
```

The `Get Element` keywords returns an XML element object, you need its `text` attribute. The output is the following:

[image]

Comment: I get the error when using the keyword you have suggested. I have modified the question to add the error I get when using these keywords. Please help in resolving the issue.

Comment: @JCDani The `${API_response_Data}` variable is not an XML so what I have suggested would not work. It should work if you could pass the actual response from the SOAP UI as an XML with all the tags. A. Kootstra has a suggestion for doing that.